# Uploading Image To Database & Storing Link or Storing Link To Offsite Image - Which is safer?

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo

My sites profile system will have something like a Facebook profile, an image at the top and a profile image. My question is a simple one: Is it safer to upload the file directly to my server and store a link in the database or store a link to an offsite image in my database?

Comment: there is no "safety" difference

Comment: This question is probably more suitable to be posted in http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fred-ii- i was thinking http://english.stackexchange.com/ then perhaps we could work out what *safety* means in this context

Comment: What's your definition of "safer"? If you mean security, it has no bearing whatsoever. Your primary concerns are going to be implementation complexity and disk usage versus reliability/lifespan of the linked image.

Comment: @Dagon That *could* work. If only I could read English; well, *Olde* English that is.

Comment: Well, how "safe" is that "offsite server"?

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on what you mean by 'safer'. If storage isn't an issue I'd upload to the server; your loading times will be faster and the image's existence will be guaranteed.